# Can I use a Canon SX 30 camera as webcam?

Tags: webcam, camera

Can I use my Canon SX 30 as my web cam?

I have come along a lot of tutorials and videos telling us how to do this using ZoomBrowser that is shipped along with the camera. But it seems that canon sx 30 is not compatible with it. Is there any other way by which we can do it?

Comment: There’s a program that can act as a shim between any device that can be used as a VFW (video-for-windows) source and webcam software, allowing you to use things like USB cameras and TV tuners as a webcam. There is a question here on SuperUser where someone asked about it and I linked them to the software (but I don’t recall what it was right now).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Unfortunately, the AV & HDMI outputs of the SX30 are only for reviewing recorded media on a tv/monitor and not capable of live view or EVF through video output. It is also not recognized as a video source in the computer because the camera does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at [the specs](http://www.photographyblog.com/reviews/canon_powershot_sx30is_review/specifications/), it seems to have a composite A/V output, like my Canon Ixus, which you could connect to a video capture card (like an old analogue Hauppauge WinTV card).  Some software, like Windows Live Messenger, for example, can use that as a webcam source.  There also appears to be an HDMI output, which would be easier to connect, but I do not know if any chat clients can use that as a video source.  It all depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: That’s exactly what I did with our video camera years ago when video-chatting was still new and cool (and I had any interest in it).

Answer (score 0):

(Okay, I found [the question](https://superuser.com/questions/238003/tvtuner-as-webcamera/253738#253738).)

If you can connect your camera to your computer and use it as a video source (check its manual for advanced usage), you can use [SplitCam](http://splitcam.biz/) to emulate a webcam with it.

Answer (score 0):

If it has HDMI output you can buy an inexpensive (€20) HDMI-to-USB converter and turn it into a webcam. However if could be problematic if the camera auto-shuts down after 5 minutes due to inactivity. That seems to be a common problem with that setup.